# React menu bar for folders, subfolders and files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, jsx

I'm working on a todo list application in React.js.  I would like to implement a side menu bar in which I can create folders, subfolders and files.  Within each subfolder, I want the default component to be my `Todo` list component.  As an example, the menubar hierarchy would mimic this:

[image]

How can I go about this.  I'm thinking of using react router and matching routes to each individual todo list.  However, I wasn't sure if I'd be able to create routes "on the fly" whenever someone created a new todolist.  What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you are using React router, use params to identify specific todo list. You can use todo id or name or anything unique as parameter . /todos/:id